# Why i cannot alter the sequence of a table?

Tags: postgresql

Tried with

```
SELECT setval(ScanResults_Id_seq, (SELECT MAX("Id") from "ScanResults"), true);
```

and also with

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ScanResults_Id_seq RESTART WITH (SELECT MAX("Id") from "ScanResults");
```

using the sequence also in lower case but I continue to get the same error:

> SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: The relation "scanresults_id_seq" does not
> exist

Looking at the dependencies of the table I can see the sequence name

[image]

I'm not an expert so I've seen that this dependency has the same name of the Sequence and I just assumed It is it.

Comment: Note that I've tried the "setval" funciton also using false as last parameter and removing it.

Comment: Resolved using quotes on the "ALTER SEQUENCE" as said in the original question, unable to use the "setval()" function also with quotes